# Spreadsheet to track word usage in a Text document?

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, words

Is there a way I can use a spreadsheet to track and display the amount of grouped words in a text document (eg MS Word or LibreOffice) as a graph?

So for example - I have 100 page word document. Then I have groupings of words; `list 1` I call "food" and include all the food items I can (Banana, steak etc), `list 2` has a group called "color" (Blue, red, etc), `list 3` has a group called "proper names" (Alex, Rachel, Tim etc)

The result I'd then be looking for in a spreadsheet is to have page numbers down the bottom, word usage frequency going top to bottom.

Plotting for every list, showing the total time words in the list are used eg page 6 has 4 usuages of "red", 2 "blue" and 3 "green"- all words on the list, so it would be plotted at 9 usgaes of list 2.

So that by looking at the spreadsheet you can see how many words from each list you have used on each page, which pages use none of the words from a particular list.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Yes it is possible.  You could create a macro in Excel to import the text, search for keywords, and count them.

Comment: Sounds like a good usecase for VBA to me too. Let us know if you have a specific question about the code you will be writing to pull this off.